# Socket io communicating from raspberry pi to Arduino in js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, arduino, raspberry-pi4

I try to communicate from my raspberry pi to my Arduino in js.
I created a server (app.js)

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var index = fs.readFileSync( 'index.html');
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
const parsers = SerialPort.parsers;
const parser = new parsers.Readline({
    delimiter: '\r\n'
});

var port = new SerialPort('/dev/tty.wchusbserialfa1410',{ 
    baudRate: 9600,
    dataBits: 8,
    parity: 'none',
    stopBits: 1,
    flowControl: false
});

port.pipe(parser);

var app = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(index);
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    
    socket.on('motor',function(data){
        
        console.log( data );
        
        port.write( data.status );
    
    });
    
});

app.listen(3000);
```

This part of the script is at the end of my html

```
<script>
            
        var socket = io();

document.getElementById("Motor1_On").onclick = function () {
  socket.emit("motor", { status: "1" });
};

</script>
```

This is working fine. I tried to place the script in an separate file within an init function which is on body onload but it won't work. when it is at the end of the index.html in a script-block it works perfectly. I tried it in different ways. complete code in an separate .js-file. just the var socket = io () in the html file and the rest in an external file. nothing works

Comment: Are there any errors in browser console? Add `console.log('something')` to make sure script actualy executes on load. Do you use bundler (webpack, parcel) to compile html?